# Magento 1.9 shipping not showing in checkout

Tags: javascript, ajax, magento, magento-1.9

I have a magento 1.9 site, My onepage checkout was working perfectly till today morning. WHen I tried to do checkout procces, I can enter billing address, but

> when I click in continue button nothing happens other than loading
>   image appears.

I have googled it and checked many tutorials even in stackoverflow, still couldn't get an answer. I had a look in

> google console and didn't shown any error

, only one warning about webkit animation. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Do you have firebug installed in your browser. If yes check for the ajax hit and return value from saveBilling Action.

Comment: when I check google console it gives me one warning.. "'webkitRequestAnimationFrame' is vendor-specific. Please use the standard 'requestAnimationFrame' instead."

Comment: I am not familiar with ajax. Can you please have a look at http://pulukool.in.

Comment: When you hit your savebilling controller it returns error : kindly check this error <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in <b>/home/hercall/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php</b> on line <b>134</b><br />

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled PHP Soap latest version. It solved my issue. Thank you.